# Changing Date format with certain conditions (combining columns)

Tags: r, date, time, formatting

I am new to R and I have run into a problem. I have a CSV file and I have date and time column combined and in a specific format.The format for the Date column is not consistent(there are two formats).I want them in the specific format in a new column called rtime as demonstrated in the example below.

```
Date           Time           rtime       
01-Sep-15     11:33:40    2015-09-01 11:33:40
01-Sep-15     11:33:50    2015-09-01 11:33:50
04/24/16      00:00:10    2016-04-24 00:00:10
04/24/16      00:00:20    2016-04-24 00:00:20
```

I have used a code that worked individually for the 01-Sep-15 format.Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `parse_date_time` from `lubridate` which can take multiple formats

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(rtime = parse_date_time(paste(Date, Time),
         c("%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S")))
#       Date     Time               rtime
#1 01-Sep-15 11:33:40 2015-09-01 11:33:40
#2 01-Sep-15 11:33:50 2015-09-01 11:33:50
#3  04/24/16 00:00:10 2016-04-24 00:00:10
#4  04/24/16 00:00:20 2016-04-24 00:00:20
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("01-Sep-15", "01-Sep-15", "04/24/16", 
"04/24/16"), Time = c("11:33:40", "11:33:50", "00:00:10", "00:00:20"
 )), .Names = c("Date", "Time"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: Hi akrun, it doesn't seem to add the rtime column. I added the csv file using this code `filename <- read_csv("~path")`  The example I gave is what the formats looked like, there is actually 24,000 observation mixed with this format.

Comment: @Ani - it does. akrun has provided a complete, reproducible example which clearly adds the extra `rtime` column in the mutate. Have you overwritten the original `df1` with the new results like `df1 <- df1 %>% ...` ?